# "Resúmen de la edición": Sobra la tilde

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

Al ir a realizar una edición en una pregunta he encontrado que el título del campo del mensaje de edición aparece el texto:

> Resúmen de la edición

La palabra *resumen*, sin embargo, no lleva tilde en español (llana terminada en n), y debería por tanto decir:

> Resumen de la edición

Comment: Ya reporté el error en [Transifex](http://transifex.com) (la herramienta que usamos para traducir Stack Overflow) Cuando esté aprobada te comento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El cambio ya está online:

[image: Campo: Resumen de la edición]